# listview not getting update

Tags: android, listview

I have been using simple adapter listview and I having problem that my listview not getting update despite calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); so is it working in simple adapter? below is my code for simple adapter.
I have declared simple adapter globally

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getActivity(), ssLst,
                        R.layout.surgerysch_item, new String[]{
                        TAG_SIMRDNO, TAG_SIPNME, TAG_SISEX,
                        TAG_SIDOB, TAG_SIPROC, TAG_SIOTNME,
                        TAG_SIOTME, TAG_DRNAME}, new int[]{R.id.txtsimrdNo,
                        R.id.txtsiptnNme, R.id.txtsiSex,
                        R.id.txtsiDob, R.id.txtsiProc,
                        R.id.txtsiotNme, R.id.txtsiotTme, R.id.txtDrnme});

                lstViw.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` before setting it to listview

Comment: @Enlightened how are you getting arrayList inside `SimpleAdapter`?are you creating new Object or just a reference ?

Comment: There's no point in calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); immediately after setting the adapter. Post the SimpleAdapter class.

Comment: send adapter class and and activity class

Comment: @mahadev,@janki I have solved it by using BaseAdapter and I have called   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); before setting adapter to listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it for that I have created separate class for adapter and I have extended by BaseAdapter so following is my code

public class SurgeryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public SurgeryAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.surgerysch_item, null);

    TextView txt_Mrdno = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtsimrdNo);
    TextView txt_Ptnnme = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtsiptnNme);
    TextView txt_Sex = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtsiSex);
    TextView txt_Dob = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtsiDob);
    TextView txt_Proce = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtsiProc);
    TextView txt_Otnme = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtsiotNme);
    TextView txt_Ottme = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtsiotTme);
    TextView txtdrNme = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtDrnme);
    TextView txtanstetic = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtAnesthestist);


    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item = data.get(position);

    //Setting all values in listview
    txt_Mrdno.setText(item.get("mrd_no"));
    txt_Ptnnme.setText(item.get("pname"));
    txt_Sex.setText(item.get("sex"));
    txt_Dob.setText(item.get("dob"));
    txt_Proce.setText(item.get("procedure"));
    txt_Otnme.setText(item.get("otName"));
    txt_Ottme.setText(item.get("otTime"));
    txtdrNme.setText(item.get("docName"));
    txtanstetic.setText(item.get("anesthetists"));
    return vi;
}
```

}

I have called  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in my fragment before  setting  adapter to listview

Comment: Hello Lakshman please use pojo class for effective code

Comment: k  mahadev i will use it thanks for ur suggestion